# Project containing white spaces

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store, application-loader

I've created a project with white space in the name. I've completed the project, but at the time of submission using Application Loader, it tells me that I need to have no white space. Is there any way to remove the white space? I'd be so grateful. I am poised for submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove any white spaces from the file name of the zip (iOS) or the pkg (Mac) file that you are submitting with Application Loader. That should do the trick.

Comment: sorry the thing i m doing using xcode i changed the zip file name as lwcfproject(project)...but in the Archived Application section i m still getting lwcf project1

Comment: Are you using Application Loader or Xcode for the submission?

Comment: @thanks for ur effort i was able to solve by clicking rename project option available